# Finding an Example Matrix $A$ Such that Column Matrices are Basic Solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

For column matrices $[1,1,2,1]^{T}$ and $[2,1,-1,0]^{T}$ that are basic solutions to the homogeneous system $AX=0$.

My initial thought was to set $A=[a, b,c,d]$ and let X be the two columns above. Then set those results equal and solve, which results $3c +d =a$. This would then mean you'd have to take arbitrary values of one of these variables to solve the other two. Is this a sufficient (or at all correct) answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero vector, of course!

Your instincts were correct, generally:

Let $A = (a,b,c,d)$. Then multiplying it by the two above gives us the system:

$$a+b+2c+d = 0$$
$$2a+b-c+0 = 0$$

Put these in a matrix, and row reduce as usual for solving a linear system of equations:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2&1\\2&1&-1&0\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&1&2&1\\0&-1&-5&-2\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-3&-1\\0&1&5&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Then parameterize with $c = s$ and $d = t$:

$$a = 3s + t, b = -5s-2t$$

So our solution set, for all $s$ and $t$ is:

$$s\begin{bmatrix}3\\-5\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$$

**After clarification:**

The asker has clarified that they intend the two vectors given to be the parameters describing the solutions. Then we simply work backwards to determine $A$:

$$s\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\\1\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$$

We want to reconstruct this in a slightly different way (add $-2$ of the second to the first). This gives us a parameterization where $d = s$ and $c=t$:

$$s\begin{bmatrix}5\\3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$$

So we have the systems:
$$a = 5s-2t, b = 3s-t, c = t, d = s$$

Then we can recover the row-reduced matrix $A$:

$$\textbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&-5\\0&1&1&-3\end{bmatrix}$$

Any matrix constructed from row operations on this matrix will have the solution set given.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I understood the question to mean that [1,1,2,1] and [2,1,-1,0] are the basic solutions (s,t) and that we need to find an example matrix A (that can be anything) that gives these.

Comment: They are solutions. Take any matrix $A$ with row vectors as described above. Or are you saying that the two vectors you gave parameterize the solutions?.

Comment: Your clarification makes perfect sense. Thanks very much.